# Vue Enterprise Boilerplate: sass-loader unable to load from updated .scss files

Tags: vue.js, sass, scss-mixins

I'm rewriting an existing project using the latest vue enterprise boilerplate.  I haven't been able to find any examples of the use of vue enterprise boilerplate so I'm doing trial and error. When using some of the existing code with large `<style>` blocks I'm running into compile problems importing from `.scss` files which are all in the directory `src/design/`. This code

```
<style lang="scss" module>
@import '@design';

.container {
  @extend %relative-block;
...
```

throws this error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend %relative-block !optional" to avoid this error.
   ╷
86 │   @extend %relative-block;
   │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  /home/dean/src/vue/examples/rewrite.0/src/components/nav-bar.vue 86:3  root stylesheet
```

The relative-block exists in the `design/_positioning.scss` file and Intellij is able to find it

```
%relative-block {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

I also get errors when using `sass @mixins`:

```
@include lq-size(100%, 100%);
```

gives

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
50 │   @include lq-size(100%, 100%);
   │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  /home/dean/src/vue/examples/rewrite.0/src/app.vue 50:3  root stylesheet
```

The `@mixin lq-size` exists and Intellij finds it in `design/_mixins.css`:

```
@mixin lq-size($width, $height) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}
```

These errors occur for code in new `.scss` files that I've added to the `src/design/` directory, and for new code in existing `.scss` files.

I'm new to `sass` and `scss`.  When I update a `.scss` file of add a new `.scss` file into the `src/design/` folder do I have to tell the `sass-loader` to look for updated `.scss` files?

Comment: did you fix this problem? @Dean Schulze